# Story of swayambhuva Shrinathji temple

Tags: krishna, temple

What is the story of self manifested Shrinathji Temple story of Rajasthan?

Comment: You mean the Dwaraka temple?

Comment: I have visited Shri nathji of rajasthan. I have no idea of dwarka

Comment: Sri nath ji temple is maintained by Rudra Sampradaya followers of Vaishnavism. They are direct followers of Vallabhacharya. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudra_Sampradaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Story of Shri Nathji:
Shri Nathji temple is main temple for followers of [Rudra Sampradaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudra_Sampradaya) in Vaishnavism which was propagated by [Vallabhacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vallabha_Acharya)

**History**

The Swarup or divine form of Shrinathji is said to be self-manifested.The idol of the Lord Krishna was being transferred to a safer place from Govardhan to protect it from the anti-Hindu, iconoclastic and barbarian destruction of the Mughal ruler Aurangzeb by the Head Goswami of the 1st House of Pushti Marg in 1669, Shri Dauji Maharaj. When the idol reached the spot at village Sihad or Sinhad, the wheels of bullock cart in which the idol was being transported sank axle-deep in mud and could not be moved any farther. The accompanying priests realised that the particular place was the Lord's chosen spot and accordingly, a temple was built there under the rule and protection of the then Maharana Raj Singh of Mewar.Shrinathji Temple is also known as 'Haveli of Shrinathji’ (mansion).The temple was built by Goswami priests in 1672.

**Legend**

It is believed Shrinathji used to travel to Mewar to play dice with a Princess by the name of Ajab Kauri. She was upset whenever her beloved Shrinathji would go back to Vraj and asked him to stay with her in the palace. Lord Shrinathji said that one day He would make her palace His home. This palace is the current temple of Shrinathji.

Presently, Shrinathji is worshiped by priests from this kul (genealogical descendants) of Vallabhacharya, in all Havelis around the world, which have also been established exclusively by them.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinathji_Temple)